# Android Game Loop: How to reach an average of 60 FPS?

Tags: java, android, loops, frame-rate

I have seen the game Airplane Madness rendering the screen at a constant average of 60 FPS on my HTC Wildfire S. I've been trying to imitate the results on the same smartphone, but I just can't understand why my program only tops 15 FPS on average?

How I can view the frame rate of Airplane Madness, you may ask? There's an option to toggle FPS counter in the Settings. I set mine to ENABLED.

Here's my code. This is my game loop. There are some interesting results from this:

```
    public void run() {
        // Average FPS for Android is 15 on Test Phone is 13 through 15.
        // Max FPS is 20.
        // Occasional bursts of FPS60 may occur.
        long now, lastTime = System.nanoTime();
        double process = 0.0;
        final double NSperTick = 1000000000.0 / 60.0;
        while (running) {
            now = System.nanoTime();
            process += (now - lastTime) / NSperTick;
            lastTime = now;
            boolean ticked = false;
            while (process >= 1) {
                process -= 1;
                tick();
                ticked = true;
            }
            if (ticked) {
                render();
            }
            swap();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

**Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong, what needs to be improved, etc., so that I can get an average of 60 FPS?** This game loop, when running in Java (Not Android), it runs practically fine, so I'm not sure what logic parts are affecting the frame rate in my smartphone.

Thanks in advance.

---

EDIT: Looks like I need to make all functions known to Man.

```
private void render() {
    synchronized (holder) {
        if (holder.getSurface().isValid()) {
            Canvas c = holder.lockCanvas();
            c.drawRGB(0x44, 0x55, 0xff);
            ball.render(c);
            holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
        }
    }
}

private void swap() {
}

private void tick() {
    float[] values = {meter.X, meter.Y, meter.Z};
    ball.tick(values);
    handler.tick(ball);
}
```

And here's how I check my game's average FPS:

```
public void run() {
    // Average FPS for Android is 15 on Test Phone is 13 through 15.
    // Max FPS is 20.
    // Occasional bursts of FPS60 may occur.
    long now, lastTime = System.nanoTime();
    int frames = 0;
    double process = 0.0;
    long frameTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    final double NSperTick = 1000000000.0 / 60.0;
    while (running) {
        now = System.nanoTime();
        process += (now - lastTime) / NSperTick;
        lastTime = now;
        boolean ticked = false;
        while (process >= 1) {
            process -= 1;
            tick();
            ticked = true;
        }
        if (ticked) {
            //render();
            frames++;
        }
        swap();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (frameTime <= System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000)
        {
            Log.d("FrameRate", Integer.toString(frames));
            frameTime += 1000;
            frames = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

And here are the results from DDMS:

```
03-12 14:29:21.008: D/FrameRate(3533): 14
03-12 14:29:22.061: D/FrameRate(3533): 15
03-12 14:29:23.048: D/FrameRate(3533): 14
03-12 14:29:24.033: D/FrameRate(3533): 14
03-12 14:29:25.018: D/FrameRate(3533): 14
03-12 14:29:26.000: D/FrameRate(3533): 14
03-12 14:29:27.056: D/FrameRate(3533): 15
03-12 14:29:28.047: D/FrameRate(3533): 14
03-12 14:29:29.026: D/FrameRate(3533): 14
03-12 14:29:29.995: D/FrameRate(3533): 14
03-12 14:29:31.037: D/FrameRate(3533): 15
03-12 14:29:32.015: D/FrameRate(3533): 14
```

EDIT 2: There's more info:

I have commented out this code in the render() function:

```
synchronized (holder)
```

But still, I can only achieve 14 to 15 FPS. Is this a limitation I can't break through?

Comment: And how does it behave if you don't call `render()`? That's the obvious thing you seem to be ignoring, that maybe your rendering takes more time than you have.

Comment: We can't help you without seeing what's in the methods tick(), render(),and swap()

Comment: @unwind I have added some more info for tick(), render(), and swap(). I noticed that in my render(), I have made a call to an object Ball. Should I expand the function on that at the top?

Comment: You might want to try busy-waiting instead of using `sleep()`. Game loops are one case where a busy-wait might actually be needed because `sleep()` does not give any guarantees about the maximum time slept before waking up.

Comment: @JasonNichols I have added some more info.

Comment: @TaZ I do not believe busy-waiting can fix my problem. I know that busy waiting may work faster to some degree when there are more processors available. My HTC Wildfire S only has 1, which is kind of ironic.

Comment: Yeah, it's kind of a nasty problem. It didn't occur to me to consider the fact that this is executed on a phone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand why your synchronizing in your rendering loop.  This is bad form as it may lock up your rendering thread, causing the app to appear to freeze if it can't acquire the lock immediately for any reason.  It also takes time to get acquire the lock.

If you've got your data organized in such a way that you need to get a lock in your rendering thread, you need to refactor your design.

Never synchronize in the UI thread!

Comment: Does creating a new thread, then use that thread to synchronize the holder, counts as synchronizing the UI thread?

Comment: Hello, I have added just a little more info. Removing synchronized(holder) doesn't solve the problem at all. :/

Answer (score 0):

Did u try to render less images/textures or sth? Maybe your phone is kinda too weak, or else you could try to play a little with the milliSeconds to sleep.

Comment: I am currently rendering 1 bitmap and 1 blue background to SurfaceView's Canvas. I'm not running anything that may use OpenGL ES. Also, my phone can run Airplane Madness, which I believed it's in OpenGL, at an average of 60 FPS. That means, my phone isn't that weak. I did played a little bit with the Thread.sleep() function, but it doesn't matter much at all. :/

Answer (score 0):

I strongly advice that you use a game framework such as [libgdx](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/). There are tons of samples and tutorial that would benefit your application. Not mentioning that you would port it to desktop or HTML5 in a breeze.

Comment: I have to turn down that offer. I'm not allowed to use a game framework by all means. :/